# Mathematical Statistics - Jun Shao, Theorem 5.4

Tags: statistics, taylor-expansion, central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood

I am studying Jun Shao's *Mathematical Statistics* and got a bit stuck in the proof of Theorem 5.4, which states:

> Let $u$ be a Borel function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $\int u(x)dF = 0$ and $\hat{F}$ be the MELE of F. Suppose that $U = Var(u(X_1))$ is positive definite. Then for any $m$ fixed distinct $t_1, \cdots, t_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $$\sqrt{n}[(\hat{F}(t_1),\cdots, \hat{F}(t_m) -(F(t_1),\cdots, F(t_m))] \rightarrow_d N_m(0, \Sigma_u),$$ where $$\Sigma_u = \Sigma - W^\tau U^{-1} W,$$ $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of  $\sqrt{n}[(F_n(t_1),\cdots, F_n(t_m) -(F(t_1),\cdots, F(t_m))]$, $W = (W(t_1), \cdots, W(t_m))$, and $W(t_j) = E[u(X_1)I_{(-\infty, t_j]}(X_1)]$.

Here $F_n$ is the empirical c.d.f. $F_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^n I_{(-\infty, t]}(X_i)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Shao proved only the univariate case. He first defined $\bar{u} = n^{-1}\Sigma_{i=1}^nu(X_i)$, then claim that from the "estimation equations" that $\frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^n \frac{u(X_i)}{1+\lambda_n^\tau u(X_i)} = 0$, $P(\frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^n \frac{u(X_i)}{1+\lambda_n^\tau u(X_i)} = 0) \rightarrow 1$, $\lambda_n \rightarrow_p 0$, and Taylor's expansion, $$\bar{u} = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n u(X_i)[u(X_i)]^\tau \lambda_n[1+o_p(1)],$$ and by the Strong Law of Large Numbers and the Central Limit Theorem, $$U^{-1} \bar{u} = \lambda_n + o_p(n^{-1/2}).$$ Here the $\lambda_n$ are the Lagrange multiplier satisfying $\frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^n \frac{u(X_i)}{1+\lambda_n^\tau u(X_i)} = 0$.

My questions:

1. It does not seem very obvious to me how Taylor's expansion was used in this case. Comparing the terms $\bar{u} = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^nu(X_i) = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n u(X_i)[u(X_i)]^\tau \lambda_n[1+o_p(1)]$, was he trying to expand 1? Or what was he trying to expand?
2. May you explain to me how the SLLN and CLT were used in this case to derive $U^{-1}\bar{u}$?

Here are the screenshots of the "estimation equations" (source: [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shao/stat710/s710-16.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eshao/stat710/s710-16.pdf)):
[image]
[image]

For reference, I have also included the full proof of the theorem:
[image]